# Combining Hover and click Functions Jquery

Tags: jquery

Jquery headaches today.I am now trying to combine hover and click events in my jquery, the latest edit to my hover function has cancelled out my click event, I can see why (i think). The remove class is overriding my click event.

What i want to achieve is that when i hover over a star all siblings are highlighted, basically follow the mouse, then when i have decided upon a star to choose i should be able to click it and all its siblings plus the one i clicked have the addClass method applied

What i have so far

```
/* Hover Function */
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
  $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
   }, function() {
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');
  });
});

/* Click Function */
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ratings li').click(function(){
  $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
 });
});

/* Click functions to add a value */
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#firstStar').click(function(){
  $('#hiddenRating').val(1);
 });
});

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#secondStar').click(function(){
    $('#hiddenRating').val(2);
 });
 });

 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#thirdStar').click(function(){
   $('#hiddenRating').val(3);
  });
 });

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#fourthStar').click(function(){
  $('#hiddenRating').val(4);
 });
});

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#fifthStar').click(function(){
  $('#hiddenRating').val(5);
 });
});
```

The Form

```
   <%= form_for @rating do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :ratings, :id => "hiddenRating" %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => current_user.id %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :recipe_id, :value => @recipe.id %>
   <div class="ratings">
<ul>
 <li id="firstStar"></li>
 <li id="secondStar"></li>
 <li id="thirdStar"></li>
 <li id="fourthStar"></li>
 <li id="fifthStar"></li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

Now I know there must be a better way of doing this, i have a lot of repeated code, but I am learning and would like to know of some ways to re factor this. is there a way to combine the .val methods into one?

With regards to the hover and click function I understand you can use the on method and pass hover and click? though not sure how to implement this

Any help appreciated,

Edit

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richlewis14/vZDwg/9/)

Thanks

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle please

Comment: done, though i havent included the form, just hover and click status

Comment: sorry fiddle incorrect, have updated

Comment: on a side note, you really should have only one document ready function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try simplifying your javascript.

```
$(function () {
    $('#stars li').hover(function () {
        var li = $(this);
        li.prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
        }, function () {
        var li = $(this);
        li.prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');
    });

    $('#stars li').click(function () {
        var li = $(this);
        $('#rating').text(li.data('rating'));
    });
})();
```

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVyXz/1/

Comment: There is no point caching a selector if your not reusing it. its good practice but totally not required for this answer

Comment: Agreed, just habit I guess as most of the event handlers I've been writing of recent have been more complicated.

Comment: I noticed that you are using data-attribute selectors, i guess this enables me to simplify my passing of a value?

Comment: I used the data-rating, so that you only need one event handler. This way if you move to a 10 star system, you don't have to change your js code to handle it, only your markup.

Comment: ah brilliant, that will make things easier, but having trouble seeing how i can implement in my setup, i get that i can add data-rating 1, data-rating 2 etc, but passing the val, at the moment i do this

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#fifthStar').click(function(){
  $('#hiddenRating').val(5);
 });
});

Comment: i also notice that when i click a star it doesnt stay highlighted? apologies but thats what i wanted to achieve aswell

Comment: I updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Brocco/PVyXz/2/ based upon your request and mdmullinax's idea. You can change the CSS to be whatever color you prefer. As for setting your hidden's value: change this line $('#rating').text(li.data('rating')); and set your val to li.data('rating')

Comment: so in my case it would become $('#hiddenRating').val(li.data('rating');  is that right? doesnt look right to me? and thanks very much for your help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24834/discussion-between-brocco-and-richlewis)

Answer (score 3):

I have added two global variables `clicked` and `chosed_index`
 if you want to also make it selected to the last element the hover did reached you can by adding

```
chosed_index = $(this).index() + 1;  // in the hover listener
```

**jQuery Updated Code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked = false; 
    var chosed_index = -1 ; 
    $('.ratings li').on('hover', function(){

           $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');         
           $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar'); 

    }); 

    $('.ratings li').on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');  


            $(".ratings li:nth-child("+chosed_index+")").prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');


    }); 



    $('.ratings li').click(function(){

        clicked = true; 
        chosed_index = $(this).index() + 1; 

        $(this).siblings().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
    });
  });
```

**Check the fiddle update**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sedz/vZDwg/12/)

I hope this can help :)

Comment: this is best because it retains the last selection

Comment: Thanks :) @tmsimont, glad I am improving my skills and helping others

Comment: I was just working on a very similar function - but you were faster ;-) I would just add another improvement by removing the `ID` in the `<li>`-elements so you can use this snippet for more than one "star-rating"-element.

Answer (score 1):

Add a "locked" class to the parent, so your JS knows if a selection has been made.  Then only act on hover out if the selection is not made.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // hover function
  $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
     $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
     $('.ratings').removeClass('locked');
   }, function() {
     if (!$('.ratings').hasClass('locked')) {
       $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');
     }
  });
  //click function 
  $('.ratings li').click(function(){
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
    $('.ratings').addClass('locked');
  });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q86b9/1/

Answer (score 1):

use a separate class for the hover (one that is a shade or so lighter than gold)

can also clear the goldstar class on click for all `li`'s for subsequent clicks

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/vZDwg/14/

```
.ratings ul li.goldstarHover {
    color:yellow;
}
```

```
/* Hover Function */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ratings li').hover(function () {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstarHover');
    }, function () {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('goldstarHover');
    });
});

/* Click Function */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.ratings li').click(function () {
        $('.ratings li').removeClass('goldstar');
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is slightly different, works like a charm tho.
Might be far simpler for some to understand. 
The `CSS` does alot of the legwork using a parent class to override `.savedgoldstar` colors

http://jsfiddle.net/vZDwg/13/

```
/* Hover Function */
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ratings li').hover(function(){
     $(this).parent().addClass('hovered');
     $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('goldstar');
   }, function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hovered');
    $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('goldstar');
  });
});

/* Click Function */
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ratings li').click(function(){
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('savedgoldstar');
  $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('savedgoldstar');
 });
});
```